# Symfony 4 - how to use service tags when autowiring an entire path

Tags: php, symfony, service, configuration, autowired

I'm working on a bundle for Symfony 4 that is structured like this:

```
\Acme
  \FooBundle
    \Article
      \Entity
        - Article.php
        - Comment.php
      \Form
        - ArticleType.php
      \Repository
        - ArticleRepository.php
        - CommentRepository.php
      - ArticleManager.php
    \User
      \Entity
        - User.php
      \Repository
        - UserRepository.php
      - UserManager.php
    \SomethingElse
      \Entity
        - SomethingElse.php
      \Repository
        - SomethingElseRepository.php
      - SomethingElseManager.php
```

There are many more folders and entities, but is irrelevant for the question.

Autowiring all the classes in that folder can be created with a config like this one:

```
Acme\FooBundle\:
    resource: '../../*/{*Manager.php,Repository/*Repository.php}'
    exclude: '../../{Manager/BaseManager.php,Repository/BaseRepository.php}'
    autowire: true
```

But when you need to add service tags like `doctrine.repository_service`, this kind of configuration won't help no more. Without the tag, when using in controller like:

```
$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository(Bar::class)
```

or

```
$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository(Bar::class)
```

it throws an error:

> The "Acme\FooBundle\SomethingElse\Repository\SomethingElseRepository" entity repository implements "Doctrine\Bundle\DoctrineBundle\Repository\ServiceEntityRepositoryInterface", but its service could not be found. Make sure the service exists and is tagged with "doctrine.repository_service".

The thing is that, since they all reside in the same root folder I'm not allowed to use a config like the following one, because it would have duplicated `Acme\FooBundle\` keys:

```
Acme\FooBundle\:
    resource: '../../*/{*Manager.php}'
    exclude: '../../{Manager/BaseManager.php}'
    autowire: true

Acme\FooBundle\:
    resource: '../../*/{Repository/*Repository.php}'
    exclude: '../../{Repository/BaseRepository.php}'
    autowire: true
    tags: ['doctrine.repository_service']
```

So, I was wondering if there's a workaround that I couldn't find or I should just manually add each and every service?

**Edit:**
It would have been a nice feature to be able to use an annotation in the class so when it's loaded it "knows" it's tag, but I'm thinking it works the other way around, loading a class because is was tagged with a certain tag.

Comment: Don't know if it will work but have you tried excluding the repository directories (using a wildcard) from your first resource?  That might prevent the duplicated keys.  What I don't see if how you are preventing your entities from being defined as services which could have amusing implications.

Comment: The resource is restricted to files ending in ```*Manager.php``` and in ```*Repository.php```, so the entities are not services.

Comment: Bit off topic but I'm curious as to where this doctrine.repository_service tag is coming from.  If your repository extends ServiceEntityRepository then no tag is needed for autowiring.  Make sure you are extending not implementing.

Comment: This might be relevant: https://github.com/symfony/maker-bundle/issues/98

Comment: So looking at the DoctrineBundle ServiceRepositoryCompilerPass, you only need the tag if you are not using autoloading.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error message after upgrading to symfony 4.4 from 3.4.

The issue seemed to be that the entity had an annotation to `@ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\MyRepository")`
while the repository extends `ServiceEntityRepository` and in the constructor points to the entity `parent::__construct($registry, MyEntity::class);`.

Removing the annotation on the entity fixed the issue.

Comment: Thank you a million, sir! I tried autotagging through services.yml as mentioned in another answer, but this has brought me happiness. Autotagging is not necessarry after all.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same error message after refactoring (renaming) some entities and the related repositories using PhpStorm 2019.2 The refactor did not update the repository class name in the doc block for the entity:

```
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\OldRepository")
```

So I used right-click > `Copy Reference` to get the fully qualified name of `NewRepository` and pasted it in to the doc block reference:

```
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="\App\Repository\NewRepository")
```

PhpStorm prefixed the class with a backslash and I didn't notice until after trying many combinations of suggested solutions for this error. I only needed to remove the backslash and the error is gone:

```
* @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="App\Repository\NewRepository")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can autoconfigure tags in your Kernel / Main Bundle Class:

https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/tags.html#autoconfiguring-tags

```
<?php

namespace Acme\FooBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerBuilder;

class FooBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function build(ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        parent::build($container);

        $container->registerForAutoconfiguration(EntityRepository::class)
            ->addTag('doctrine.repository_service');
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, @MakG! Tried it in bundle and in kernel too, as specified in the documentation. Unfortunately, it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can tag all of your repositories, like this:

```yaml
App\Repository\:
        resource: '../src/Repository'
        autowire: true
        tags: ['doctrine.repository_service']
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @t-van-den-berg and @arleigh-hix !

I had this problem after migrating from Symfony 3.4 to 4.4, when I wanted to use old Repositories with new services.

My solution was a little variation:

```
use App\Repository\NewRepository;
//...
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass=NewRepository::class)
 */
```

And service declaration (to use Interface):

```yaml
  App\Repository\NewRepository:
    arguments:
      - "@doctrine"
  App\Repository\NewRepositoryInterface: '@App\Repository\NewRepository'
```